# python - How do use basehttpserver to save files sent using POST

Tags: python, http, post, server

I can't find an example of how to set up a http server in python, which saves files to a directory which are sent to it using HTTP POST with urllib2, requests or curl.

I want to use it as part of a program where a client analyses data, and sends the results file back to the server. The server saves the file to a directory where the results are analysed.

Thanks

Comment: https://snipt.net/raw/f8ef141069c3e7ac7e0134c6b58c25bf/?nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this recently using the CGI module in Python. 
My POST method and file copy process are below. 
It uses a form, where `sfname` is the full path of where the file had to saved and `file` is the file itself. This is slightly more complex than what you need, but it should get you going.

```
def do_POST(self):
    f = StringIO()
    fm = cgi.FieldStorage(fp=self.rfile, headers=self.headers, environ={'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST'})
    if "file" in fm:
        r, resp, info = self.get_file_data(fm)
        print r, info, "by: ", self.client_address
        if r:
            f.write("File upload successful: %s" % info)
            f.seek(0)
            if resp == 200: 
                # Do stuff here
            else:
                # Error handle here
        else:
            f.write("File upload failed: %s" % info)
            f.seek(0)
            if resp == 200: 
                # Do stuff here
            else:
                # Error handle here
        if f:
            copyfileobj(f, self.wfile)
            f.close()
    else:
        # Error handle here

def get_file_data(self, form):
    fn = form.getvalue('sfname')
    fpath, fname = ospath.split(fn)
    if not ospath.isabs(fpath):
        return (False, 400, "Path of filename on server is not absolute")
    if not ospath.isdir(fpath):
        return (False, 400, "Cannot find directory on server to place file")
    try:
        out = open(fn, 'wb')
    except IOError:
        return (False, 400, "Can't write file at destination. Please check permissions.")
    out.write(form['file'].file.read())
    return (True, 200, "%s ownership changed to user %s" % (fn, u))
```

Also, this were the packages I imported. You might not need all of them.

```
from shutil import copyfileobj
from os import path as ospath
import cgi,
import cgitb; cgitb.enable(format="text")
try:
    from cStringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from StringIO import StringIO
```

I tested it with `curl -F "file=@./myfile.txt" -F "sfname=/home/user/myfile.txt" http://myserver` and it worked fine. Can't guarantee the other methods. Hope this helps.

Comment: can you please upvote or mark as correct? I'm trying to build some rep here... ;-)